# I'm confused with this acceleration thing

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This Brilliant instead of educating me makes me feel stupid. Could you help me out and show me what those "few algebraic steps" are? I tried to get the same result but what I have is very different, and I don't know why, even though it's supposed to be a cinch. It's, I guess, purely mathematical, so I figured I'll try asking it here

*Quoted text*:

> \begin{align}
> \Delta x & = v_0t + \frac12 t\Delta v \\
>          & = v_0t + \frac12 at^2
> \end{align}
>
> Finally, because we can often measure distances more precisely than times, it's useful to relate directly the final speed $v_t$ to how far it's moved $\Delta x$.  It takes a few algebraic steps to accomplish, but eliminating $t$ in the previous equation by plugging in $t = \Delta v/a$ does the trick.  The result is the third kinematic equation
>
> $$
> v_t^2-v_0^2 = 2a\Delta x
> $$

[Original at https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PP9S.jpg]

*Attempt*:
[image]

Comment: Your screen shot is way too big, and your photo of your attempt is too blurry to read.

Comment: @coffeemath it's readable, I checked

Comment: Well it's blurry compared to other screen shots I've seen here, also has some crossed off stuff. It wouldn't take much to do a no error crossed out version and take a sharper photo.

Comment: Well, I'll say that it doesn't look blurry to me, but—yeah, it's got crossed out sections, and it also appears rotated $90$ degrees, which is pretty annoying.

Comment: I'll edit in the screenshot in MathJax, but you should really learn to do MathJax and enter your attempt that way.

Comment: $(v_t - v_0)^2 \neq v_t^2 - v_0^2$

Comment: @briantung I actually tried to replace it with a non-rotated version, but SE rotates it nonetheless

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev: That's why you should enter your attempt with MathJax.  There is a learning curve, but it makes it easier to read and the search engine can index it.

Comment: @michaelseifert You're right, it's not. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Delta x= v_0t +\frac12at^2$ and $t= \dfrac{\Delta v}{a}= \dfrac{v_t-v_0}{a}$

so $\Delta x= v_0\dfrac{v_t-v_0}{a} +\frac12a\left(\dfrac{v_t-v_0}{a}\right)^2 = \dfrac{2v_0v_t-2v_0^2 +v_t^2-2v_0v_t+v_0^2}{2a} = \dfrac{v_t^2-v_0^2}{2a}$

and thus ${v_t^2-v_0^2}={2a}\Delta x$

Comment: I did it with the first one, with the tiny triangle. Could you do it? I want to know what my mistake was

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev Your error seems to be saying $(v_t-v_0)^2 =v_t^2-v_0^2$ rather than the correct $v_t^2-2v_0v_t+v_0^2$

Comment: Thanks, I got it. I've gotten rusty at math

Answer (score 2):

Start from

$$
\Delta x = v_0 t + \frac12 at^2
$$

Substitute $t = \Delta v / a$ into this, to get

\begin{align}
\Delta x
  & = v_0 \frac{\Delta v}{a} + \frac12 a \left(\frac{\Delta v}{a}\right)^2 \\
  & = \frac{v_0\Delta v}{a} + \frac{(\Delta v)^2}{2a} \\
  & = \frac{2v_0\Delta v + (\Delta v)^2}{2a} \\
  & = \frac{\Delta v(2v_0 + \Delta v)}{2a}
\end{align}

Now, $v_t = v_0 + \Delta v$, so $v_t-v_0 = \Delta v$, and $v_t+v_0 = 2v_0 + \Delta v$, giving us

$$
\Delta x = \frac{(v_t-v_0)(v_t+v_0)}{2a}
$$

or, multiplying both sides by $2a$,

$$
2a\Delta x = v_t^2 - v_0^2
$$

---

As indicated by Michael Seifert in the comments, you make an error in assuming that $v_t^2-v_0^2 = (v_t-v_0)^2$.

Comment: I did it with the first one, with the tiny triangle. Could you do it? I want to know what my mistake was

Comment: Look at Michael Seifert's comment to your original post.  That's your error.

Comment: Thanks, it is indeed my error